How to remove concurrent occurrence of comma in a dynamic string - Oracle
I have plsql which builds dynamic insert query. i am stuck when framing identified the multiple occurrence of comma.
How to replace with one comma if concurrent occurrence of command greater then 1
I have string
var1='A_CAL,B_CAL.C_CAL';
var2='';
var3='';
var4='D_CAL,E_CAL';
var5='';
var6='';
var7='';
var8='S_CAL';

when concatenating all variables and creating comma separated data it could see ,,, or ,,  or maybe more
result = var1 || ',' || var2 || ',' || var3 ||  ',' || var4 || ',' || var5 || ',' || var6 || ',' || var7 || ',' || var8

String formed like this when printed
A_CAL,B_CAL,C_CAL,,,D_CAL,E_CAL,,,,S_AL

I want like this:
A_CAL,B_CAL,C_CAL,D_CAL,E_CAL,S_AL

I tried this
replace(result,',,','') 

this only works for 2 comma. but it can be more

In Oracle, an empty string '' is identical to NULL so: check if the strings are not NULL and, if so, prepend a comma; then concatenate the strings together; and, finally, remove the leading comma.
Like this:
DECLARE
  var1 VARCHAR2(200) := 'A_CAL,B_CAL.C_CAL';
  var2 VARCHAR2(200) := NULL;
  var3 VARCHAR2(200) := NULL;
  var4 VARCHAR2(200) := 'D_CAL,E_CAL';
  var5 VARCHAR2(200) := NULL;
  var6 VARCHAR2(200) := NULL;
  var7 VARCHAR2(200) := NULL;
  var8 VARCHAR2(200) := 'S_CAL';
  list VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  list := SUBSTR(
               CASE WHEN var1 IS IS NOT NULL THEN ',' || var1 END
            || CASE WHEN var2 IS IS NOT NULL THEN ',' || var2 END
            || CASE WHEN var3 IS IS NOT NULL THEN ',' || var3 END
            || CASE WHEN var4 IS IS NOT NULL THEN ',' || var4 END
            || CASE WHEN var5 IS IS NOT NULL THEN ',' || var5 END
            || CASE WHEN var6 IS IS NOT NULL THEN ',' || var6 END
            || CASE WHEN var7 IS IS NOT NULL THEN ',' || var7 END
            || CASE WHEN var8 IS IS NOT NULL THEN ',' || var8 END,
            2
          );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(list);
END;
/

Which outputs:
A_CAL,B_CAL.C_CAL,D_CAL,E_CAL,S_CAL


Or you can use regular expressions and replace all leading commas, trailing commas or repeated commas leaving only the first of any repeated commas:
DECLARE
  var1 VARCHAR2(200) := 'A_CAL,B_CAL.C_CAL';
  var2 VARCHAR2(200) := NULL;
  var3 VARCHAR2(200) := NULL;
  var4 VARCHAR2(200) := 'D_CAL,E_CAL';
  var5 VARCHAR2(200) := NULL;
  var6 VARCHAR2(200) := NULL;
  var7 VARCHAR2(200) := NULL;
  var8 VARCHAR2(200) := 'S_CAL';
  list VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  list := REGEXP_REPLACE(
            var1 || ',' || var2 || ',' || var3 || ',' || var4
            || ',' || var5 || ',' || var6 || ',' || var7 || ',' || var8,
            '^,+|,+$|(,),+',
            '\1'
          );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(list);
END;
/

Which, although less to type, is more complicated to comprehend, probably slower than simple string functions and gives the same output.
fiddle

I suggest you to use Regex. It is short and more readable:
 String result = text.replaceAll(",+", "");


This is not valid Oracle PL/SQL syntax and (if you changed it to use valid syntax) doesn't solve the OP's problem as it will remove all commas and not repeated commas (or extra leading/trailing commas).
